# unexpected symbol in Rscript test.R

Tags: r, rscript

I just started with R and am running it from command line (OS: Mageia). So far it worked fine, I can follow the tutorial (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r) without problems, doing math, plotting, dataframes - everything works.

However if I try to run a script by using

> Rscript test.R

I'm getting the error message "unexpected Symbol in Rscript test.R" and I do not know why.

test.R is located in the same directory I started R from so I'm assuming R should find it.
 test.R itself contains:

> print(5)

and should therefore not throw any erors. I have also tried it with an empty file, same problem.

My next idea was that there is something wrong with Rscript as

> Rscript --version

gives me the errors message

> object 'Rscript' not found

However, the package "utils" that contains Rscript is installed and trying to update it does not work.

Since I'm new to R I don't know whether this is a case of me not using Rscript properly or there having been a problem with installation. I would be very glad for any help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are calling these commands from the R session.

`Rscript` is a terminal command to run the R. Open the terminal and move to the directory where `test.R` locates and try the command again.

If you want to run `test.R` from an R session, use `source` function.

```r
source("test.R")
```

Comment: You are right. Apparently I totally misunderstood how to use Rscript //blush. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, please see the edit.